# Where find default Windows 10 UWP icons

Tags: xaml, icons, win-universal-app, windows-10

I'm developing a UWP application, however I'm not able to find where are the default icons.

Where can I find a list of them?

Comment: It just uses the Segoe MDL2 [UI Symbol font](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/style/segoe-ui-symbol-font).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use character map application and select the font as segoe mdl2 assets. All the available icons will be shown. Alternatively in xaml also you can use like below code:

```
<SymbolIcon Symbol="Sync" Foreground="Red"/>
```